# Spark Dataframe join Exception thrown in awaitResult

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to join two Dataframes, one is around 10 million records and the other is about 1/3 of that. Since the small DataFrame fits comfortably in the executor's memory, I perform a broadcast join and then write out the result:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("/plablo/data/tweets10M")
  .select("id", "content", "lat", "lon", "date")
val fullResult = FilterAndClean.performFilter(df, spark)
  .select("id", "final_tokens")
  .filter(size($"final_tokens") > 1)
val fullDFWithClean = {
  df.join(broadcast(fullResult), "id")
}
fullDFWithClean
    .write
    .partitionBy("date")
    .mode(saveMode = SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .parquet("/plablo/data/cleanTokensSpanish")
```

After a while, I get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResultInForkJoinSafely(ThreadUtils.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenInner(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:209)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.consume(DataSourceScanExec.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.doProduceVectorized(DataSourceScanExec.scala:392)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.doProduce(DataSourceScanExec.scala:315)
.....
```

There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635930/spark-exception-thrown-in-awaitresult)  question that addresses the same issue. In the comments, it's mentioned that increasing `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout` could fix the problem, but after setting a large value (5000 seconds) I still get the same error (although much later, of course).

The original data is partitioned by `date` column, the function that returns `fullResult` performs a series of narrow transformations and filters the data so, I'm assuming, the partition is preserved.

The Physical Plan confirms that spark will perform a `BroadcastHashJoin`

```
*Project [id#11, content#8, lat#5, lon#6, date#150, final_tokens#339]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [id#11], [id#363], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Project [id#11, content#8, lat#5, lon#6, date#150]
:  +- *Filter isnotnull(id#11)
:     +- *FileScan parquet [lat#5,lon#6,content#8,id#11,date#150] 
Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: 
InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://geoint1.lan:8020/plablo/data/tweets10M], 
PartitionCount: 182, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: 
[IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: 
struct<lat:double,lon:double,content:string,id:int>
   +- BroadcastExchange 
HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, true] as bigint)))
      +- *Project [id#363, UDF(UDF(UDF(content#360))) AS 
 final_tokens#339]
     +- *Filter (((UDF(UDF(content#360)) = es) && (size(UDF(UDF(UDF(content#360)))) > 1)) && isnotnull(id#363))
        +- *FileScan parquet [content#360,id#363,date#502] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://geoint1.lan:8020/plablo/data/tweets10M], PartitionCount: 182, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct<content:string,id:int>
```

I believe that, given the size of my data, this operation should be relatively fast (on 4 executors with 5 cores each and 4g RAM running on YARN in cluster mode).

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you think the case that some partitions of your first dataset is to large so the result of it and the broadcast dataset is to big ??? You can checkout the size of each partition and the distribution of `id` value to verify it.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue, id is a unique row identifier so it should be evenly distributed

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this, the first question is how big is the dataframe you are trying to broadcast? It's worth estimating its size (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397777/how-can-i-find-the-size-of-a-rdd) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401696/how-do-i-figure-out-the-size-of-specific-rdds-in-the-cache) also).

Note that Spark's default `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` is [only 10Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984068/does-spark-sql-autobroadcastjointhreshold-work-for-joins-using-datasets-join-op) so you are really not supposed to broadcast very large datasets.

Your use of `broadcast` takes precedence and may be forcing Spark to do something it otherwise would choose not to do. A good rule is to only force aggressive optimization if the default behavior is unacceptable because aggressive optimization often creates various edge conditions, like the one you are experiencing.

Comment: I'm taking your advice, but at the same time, I'm partitioning both DataFrames by id. In this scenario, the default behavior is to perform a SortMergeJoin which, if I can get the partitions right should be fast enough. I'll report back

Comment: That might help but, keep in mind that partitioning by `id` will already force a shuffle for both datasets so I'm not entirely sure what you are saving since you attempted to force a broadcast in order to avoid a shuffle in the first place...

Comment: How did you wind up resolving this issue?

Comment: Hi I spotted the same error message in my glue job logs, but I still can't fix it, here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135124/glue-job-succeeded-without-stepfunction-but-failed-if-its-kicked-off-by-stepfu, could you please take a look please?

Answer (score 0):

This can also fail if `spark.task.maxDirectResultSize` is not increased. It's default is 1 megabyte (1m). Try `spark.task.maxDirectResultSize=10g`.

Comment: spark.task.maxDirectResultSize=10g shows invalid syntax.

Comment: Hi I spotted the same error message in my glue job logs, but I still can't fix it, here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135124/glue-job-succeeded-without-stepfunction-but-failed-if-its-kicked-off-by-stepfu, could you please take a look please?